# Como guardar una matriz en un vector en C#

Tags: c#, array, lista, matriz

consulta... estoy generando en un bucle una determinada cantidad de datos que se guardan en una matriz de 2 dimensiones, y la cantidad de matrices dependen de lo que ingrese el usuario. Quiero guardarlas en un vector de una dimensión pero no me esta saliendo, me da un error, como se hace? Recién arranco con C#.

El tamaño del vector esta determinado por el usuario.
La variable 'i' se incrementa en cada vuelta del bucle

```
int[,] arrayUsuarioDosDimensiones = new int[3x9];

int[] vectorUnadimension= new int[tamañoIngresadoPorUsuario];

vectorUnadimension[i] = arrayUsuarioDosDimensiones;
```

[image: Info del Error]

Comment: No me suena que  `int[3x9];` sea una sintaxis válida, pero supondré que dice `int[3, 9]`. Ahora bien, ¿Quieres meter un array de dos dimensiones en uno de una sola dimensión? No puedes hacer eso, en todo caso podrías meterlo en uno de 3 dimensiones. De cualquier manera no me queda clara la pregunta.

Comment: Hola! quería armar un vector que contenga matrices de dos dimensiones. Lo pude hacer, igualmente gracias por responder. int[,] matriz= new int[3, 9]; int[][,] matrices = new int[matrizAGenerar][,];